# How to use external js file in ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, scriptmanager

i have a control which is on update panel. i want my javascript code run every time the updatePAnel is updated.

i use something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "my_script", "runFunction();", true);
```

the problem is that my js code is huge and i want to place it in js file and use it from file. what should i change in my code ?

Answer (score 14):

You could use the `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude` method:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
    updatePanel,
    updatePanel.GetType(),
    "a_key",
    "myScript.js"
);
```

Note that this method will render your script early in the HTML, so your script should not rely on the order scripts are rendered on the page.

More about this method at http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb337005.aspx

But if your script depends on some other script, a better option is to use the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method, but instead of passing the script body as a parameter, you pass the entire `<script>` tag with your script's address:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    updatePanel,
    updatePanel.GetType(),
    "a_key",
    "<script type='text/javascript' src='my_script.js'></script>",
    false
);
```

Note that the last parameter, which sets the `addScriptTags` flag, is set to false, allowing you to render the entire tag with the `src` attribute defined.

Comment: i changed code according to Your advice, but strange thing, now i get error in my js file - Object expected. at he same time when i pass js code like a string its OK.

Comment: @user1178399, it seems like your script depends on other scripts that are being rendered after it (and, therefore, the objects you depend on are not created yet). See the complemented answer above to know what to do.

Comment: nice, at least your last explanation stopped me from further searching the net for a solution.