# How can I call a jquery function from asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm stuggling to find ways to call a jquery

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "countdown(); ", true);
```

Problem this is it trys to call the method inline so it won't execute the function which is in a external javascript file.

Any way to call my jquery function from asp.net c#?

Comment: Plenty of answers out on google...just have to search for them.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930352/how-to-use-external-js-file-in-scriptmanager-registerstartupscript

Comment: That includes a javascript file but doesn't call a function so that's not valid

Comment: Are you referencing the external js file in your aspx page?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527688/use-external-javascript-file-function-in-registerstartupscript-method

Comment: You cannot call a JavaScript function in asp.Net because the code is being executed on the server and JavaScript is executed on the client browser. What you want is to render a JavaScript call on the client to get executed when the page is rendered.

Comment: Yeah thats what I have been trying to do with that command I used before but it doesn't seem to call the function which I think is because it's in a external js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code worked. I just had to clear my cache as it was loading my old javascript file. DOH!

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "countdown(); ", true);